# Optional query parameters in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, optional-parameters

I don't understand [optional query parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/#optional-parameters) in FastAPI. How is it different from [default query parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/#defaults) with a default value of `None`?

What is the difference between `arg1` and `arg2` in the example below where `arg2` is made an optional query parameter as described in the above link?

```py
@app.get("/info/")
async def info(arg1: int = None, arg2: int | None = None):
    return {"arg1": arg1, "arg2": arg2}
```

Comment: afaik, there is no difference between them

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289969/17865804) for more details and examples.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is covered in the [FastAPI reference manual](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/), albeit just as a small note:

```
async def read_items(q: Optional[str] = None):
```

> FastAPI will know that the value of q is not required because of the default value = None.
>
> The Optional in `Optional[str]` is not used by FastAPI, but will allow your editor to give you better support and detect errors.

(`Optional[str]` is the same as `str | None` pre 3.10 for other readers)

Since your *editor* might not be aware of the context in which the parameter is populated and used by FastAPI, it might have trouble understanding the actual signature of the function when the parameter is not marked as `Optional`. You may or may not care about this distinction.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @MatsLindh, you can also use the `fastapi.Query` class with a `default` parameter set.

For example:

```py
async def get_companies(company_id: int = Query(default=None, alias="id"), limit: int = Query(default=15), page: int = Query(default=1)):
```

defines a function `get_companies,` with an optional `company_id` (parsed in the request arguments as `id`), an optional `limit`, as well as an optional `page`.

Answer (score 0):

Before 3.10 python, is:

```py
from typing import Union

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_item(item_id: str, q: Union[str, None] = None):
    if q:
        return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}
    return {"item_id": item_id}
```

referencia https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/#optional-parameters

Answer (score -3):

It depends on the way you see it, but my philosophy is:

Optional parameters are a bigger set that includes query parameters.

That is, query parameters take an input that is a value, while optional parameters are query parameters that can have no value (i.e. None).