# How to document default None/null in OpenAPI/Swagger using FastAPI?

Tags: python, database, swagger, openapi, fastapi

Using a ORM, I want to do a POST request letting some fields with a `null` value, which will be translated in the database for the default value specified there.

The problem is that OpenAPI (Swagger) **docs**, ignores the default `None` and still prompts a `UUID` by default.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
from uuid import UUID
import uvicorn


class Table(BaseModel):
    # ID: Optional[UUID]      # the docs show a example UUID, ok
    ID: Optional[UUID] = None # the docs still shows a uuid, when it should show a null or valid None value.

app = FastAPI()  
    
@app.post("/table/", response_model=Table)
def create_table(table: Table):
    # here we call to sqlalchey orm etc.
    return 'nothing important, the important thing is in the docs'
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

In the OpenAPI schema example (request body) which is at the **docs** we find:

```
{
 "ID": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
}
```

This is not ok, because I specified that the default value is `None`,so I expected this instead:

```
{
 "ID": null, # null is the equivalent of None here
}
```

Which will pass a `null` to the `ID` and finally will be parsed in the db to the default value (that is a new generated `UUID`).

Comment: Why do you have `ID: UUID` defaulted to the string `'null'`? Shouldn't it be `None`?

Comment: @npk, yes you are right, and UUID should be Optional[UUID] but that will produce in the docs a UUID not a null, basically is exactly that what I need to change to get a null in the docs.

Comment: You want your users to explicitly post null for ID in the request body? Or you just want the example in the generated docs to be different?

Comment: @JarroVGIT The second, with Optional[UUID] they can already specify the uuid if they want or putting null, but I want null to be the default value and the one documented as in most of cases you won't generate the uuid by yourself.

Comment: Basically for the documentation  ID: Optional[UUID] = None is the same as   ID: Optional[UUID]. I think in one case it should write null and in the other a example UUID

Comment: I thought I had a pretty good handle on FastAPI, but this got me stumped. I tried everything I could think of, but none of them resulted in an example with a value of 'null' without quotations. I am sorry I wasn't able to help, but wanted to let you know either way because chances are; it can't be done. Might be a good idea to open an issue on Github? Please tag me there, I am very curious if this can be done. :)

Comment: @JarroVGIT, I just posted it there and tag you: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/new?assignees=&labels=question&template=question.yml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you declare `Optional` parameters, users **shouldn't** include those parameters in the request specified with `null` or `None` (in Python), in order to be `None`. **By default**, the value of such parameters will be `None`, unless the user specifies some other value when sending the request.

Hence, all you have to do is to declare a custom `example` for the Pydantic model using `Config` and `schema_extra`, as described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/) and as shown below. The below example will create an empty (i.e., `{}`) request body in OpenAPI (Swagger UI), which can be successfully submitted (as `ID` is the only attribute of the model and is optional).

```py
class Table(BaseModel):
    ID: Optional[UUID] = None
    
    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
            }
        }

@app.post("/table/", response_model=Table)
def create_table(table: Table):
    return table
```

If the `Table` model included some other *required* attributes, you could add `example` values for those, as demonstrated below:

```py
class Table(BaseModel):
    ID: Optional[UUID] = None
    some_attr: str
    
    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "example": {
                "some_attr": "Foo"
            }
        }
```

If you would like to **keep the auto-generated examples** for the rest of the attributes **except the one for the `ID` attribute**, you could use the below to remove `ID` from the model's properties in the generated schema (inspired by [Schema customization](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#schema-customization)):

```py
class Table(BaseModel):
    ID: Optional[UUID] = None
    some_attr: str
    some_attr2: float
    some_attr3: bool
    
    class Config:
        @staticmethod
        def schema_extra(schema: Dict[str, Any], model: Type['Table']) -> None:
            del schema.get('properties')['ID']
```

Also, if you would like to add custom `example` to some of the attributes, you could use `Field()` (as described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/schema-extra-example/#field-additional-arguments)); for example, `some_attr: str = Field(example="Foo")`.

Another possible solution would be to modify the generated OpenAPI schema, as described in Solution 3 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71536816/17865804). Though, the above solution is likely more suited to this case.

#### Note

`ID: Optional[UUID] = None` is the same as `ID: UUID = None`. As previously documented in FastAPI website (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71272615/17865804)):

> The Optional in `Optional[str]` is not used by FastAPI, but will allow
> your editor to give you better support and detect errors.

Since then, FastAPI has revised their [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/it/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/) with the following:

> The Union in `Union[str, None]` will allow your editor to give you
> better support and detect errors.

Hence, `ID: Union[UUID, None] = None` is the **same** as `ID: Optional[UUID] = None` and `ID: UUID = None`. In **Python 3.10+**, one could also use `ID: UUID| None = None` (see [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/python-types/#using-union-or-optional)).

As per [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/it/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#use-query-as-the-default-value) (see `Info` section in the link provided):

> Have in mind that the **most important part to make a parameter optional**
> is the part:
>
> ```
> = None
> ```
>
> or the:
>
> ```
> = Query(default=None)
> ```
>
> as it will use that `None` as the default value, and that way make the
> parameter not required.
>
> The `Union[str, None]` part allows your editor to provide better
> support, but it is not what tells FastAPI that this parameter is not
> required.

Comment: I just want to add to this answer, that it is possible to make the `null` type required via Pydantic, in which case it would be a willingness to put `null` or `UID` in a concrete way. Of course, this does not affect the display of the example value, since swagger does not handle the `null` type. To make the `null` required : `Optional[UUID] = Field(...)` or `Optional[UUID] = ...`

Comment: This is indeed useful to know, thanks! but it doesn't quite solve the problem. If i use this solution I would need to write all the additional fields by hand in all the classes excluding the ID field.

Comment: My question explicitly asked how to document using the non quoted "null" because it still shows that you can use that field, even if it is an optional one. But if you can just skip documenting the ID would be OK for me, as long as I don't need to hardcode all other fields in the schema_extra.

Comment: @Chris, thanks! that works, it is pity that is not possible to document the null thought, but your answer is an OK alternative solution.