# How can I handle empty strings as input on my FastAPI form?

Tags: forms, fastapi

```
@router.post('/update_attributes/{username}')
def update_attributes(request: Request, username: str, email: str = Form(...)):
    pass
```

How can I handle empty strings as input on my form? I get errors if the `email` textfield on my form is not filled in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to document default None/null in OpenAPI/Swagger using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72214347/how-to-document-default-none-null-in-openapi-swagger-using-fastapi)

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804) ("About Optional Parameters" part) as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ellipses` (`...`) means it is required. So leaving it empty would result in errors. If you want it not to be required, you can replace the ellipses with `None` like so:

```
@router.post('/update_attributes/{username}')
def update_attributes(request: Request, username: str, email: str = Form(None)):
    pass
```

Comment: Do you know where this is documented? I looked hard and could not find anything.

Comment: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/?h=el#required-with-ellipsis

Although that is in the `Query` docs, the principle is the same for all parameter types (Form, File, Body etc)