# TypeError: Object of type 'type' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi

The code works fine in Postman and provides a valid response but fails to generate the OpenAPI/Swagger UI automatic docs.

```py
class Role(str, Enum):
     Internal = "internal"
     External = "external"


class Info(BaseModel):
    id: int
    role: Role

class AppInfo(Info):
    info: str


@app.post("/api/v1/create", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def create(info: Info, apikey: Union[str, None] = Header(str)):
    if info:
        alias1 = AppInfo(info="Portal Gun", id=123, role=info.role)
        alias2 = AppInfo(info="Plumbus", id=123, , role=info.role)
        info_dict.append(alias1.dict())
        info_dict.append(alias2.dict())

        
        return {"data": info_dict}
    else:
        
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            detail=f"Please provide the input"
        )
```

Error received:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'type' is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: What command are you running?

Comment: uvicorn app.main:app --reload I have a main.py in app folder

Comment: I suspect the line `role: Role` because `type` is the type of all classes in Python.

Comment: Your code does not run (`info_dict` is undefined). Please provide enough code to actually diagnose your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Issue

The reason you get the following error in the console (Note that this error could also be raised by other causes—see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804)):

```
TypeError: Object of type 'type' is not JSON serializable
```

as well as the error below in the browser, when trying to load the OpenAPI/Swagger UI autodocs at `/docs`:

```
Fetch error
Internal Server Error /openapi.json
```

is due to the following line in your code:

```py
apikey: Union[str, None] = Header(str)
                                  ^^^
```

### Solution

When declaring a [`Header` parameter](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/header-params/#header-parameters) (or any other type of parameter, i.e., `Path`, `Query`, `Cookie`, etc), the first value that is passed to the [`Header` class](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/5905c3f740c8590f1a370e36b99b760f1ee7b828/fastapi/params.py#L147) constructor (i.e., `__init__`  method) is the `default` value, which can either be `None` or some default value based on the type you specified for the parameter—in your case that could be some string value, e.g., `'some-api-key'`, **not** the type `str`). Since you defined the parameter as `Optional`, you could simply pass `None` as the default value:

```py
apikey: Union[str, None] = Header(None)
```

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289969/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804) for more details on `Optional` parameters in FastAPI.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem might be at:

```py
apikey: Union[str, None] = Header(str)
```

in the async function `create()`

Maybe the function or class `Header()` doesn't accept `str` as an input?

Although I don't really know what that function does tho//what library it is from.

Comment: I am providing the header in postman and it works fine

Comment: Can you maybe provide a backtrace to your error code?