# Pydantic, setting the attribute dynamically

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, setattribute

everyone.
Got a problem here.
I have some Pydantic model with some attrs and 99 % of the time I want it that way. But for the remaining 1 % at a time I want it to have some additional attribute.

I can set it dynamically using an **extra attribute** with the Config object and it works fine except the one thing: Pydantic knows nothing about that attr. So when I want to modify my model back by passing response via FastAPI, it will not be converted to Pydantic model completely (this attr would be a simple dict) and this isn't convenient.

Other possible options:

1. Just define another model with that attr.
   I don't consider it as I want to modify Pydantic model itself, converting to dict back and forth inefficient, model is nested and huge.
2. Make attr Optional.
   Schema will have it with *None* and it'll be passed everywhere. Not optimal, because as I said, model in general doesn't need this attribute.

So what I want is:
Maybe it's possible for Pydantic to specify that dynamically can be set attribute of specific type for this model (because I don't have stochastic mutation, I definitely know what would be added), but the general instance of that class will not have it anywhere. And when I set it, Pydantic will handle new structure of my model and will not have any problem with that. I couldn't find anything similar by myself.

Thanks in advance. Would be glad for any help.
P.S. I hope I explained myself very clearly and the code is unnecessary as problem's very straightforward.

Comment: I'd define a model with all expected attributes with some of those being optional. I think this is a safer way of doing things.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76131296/17865804)

Comment: If the behavior of your router with or without this attr doesn't change you can make it optional but if not i would suggest to create a new class that inheritat from your model, to have a better readability