# Getting error 422 "Unprocessable Entity" in my FastAPI / Python demo API

Tags: python, postman, backend, fastapi

I'm relatively new to Python and I'm working on a demo backend project which is a users API in with FastAPI.

My API is connected to a MongoDB database to save the data.

I'm seeing this error on postman when I try to add a new user:

[image]

This is my model class for User:

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str]  # Optional and str for mongo
    username: str
    email: str
```

And this is the logic in my endpoint to create the new User:

```
@router.post("/", response_model=User, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)  # status_code = default code if OK
async def create_user(new_user: User):
    # if user is found in the database, raise an exception
    if type(search_user("email", new_user.email)) == User:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, detail="User already exists.")
    # else, create the user
    new_user_dict = dict(new_user) 
    del new_user_dict["id"]
    user_id = db_client.users.insert_one(new_user_dict).inserted_id 
    transformed_user = user_schema(db_client.users.find_one({"_id": user_id}))
    return User(**transformed_user)
```

I already compared line by line the code from my tutor, and I see no differences but mine does not work... can somebody help me solve this problem? By the way... Im using Python 3.11..

Comment: You're sending the `username` and `email` fields, but it looks like it also expected the `id` and `body` fields...

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289969/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804) on how to properly declare optional parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone for your comments, I found that the problem was being generated in an auxiliary function (search_user). I was not handling correctly, the case where the id is None like many of you mentioned here... I'm closing the question, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unintuitive, but `Optional` in python only meanst that the value can also be `None`. It doesn't actually make `id` optional, to achieve that, you must provide a default value:

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str] = None
    username: str
    email: str
```