# Optional str in Pydantic 2.0 with field constraints

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, optional-parameters

I am trying to define an optional string field in Pydantic 2.0 that should follow the constraints (if provided), else pass `None`. However, none of the below implementation is working and it is giving the same error.

```
    Option1: 
    role_desc: Annotated[
    str | None,
    Field(
        min_length=5,
        max_length=200,
        examples=["Role description is provided here"],
        default=None,
    ),
]
   Option 2:
   role_desc: Annotated[
    Optional[str],
    Field(
        min_length=5,
        max_length=200,
        examples=["Role description is provided here"],
        default=None,
    ),
]
 Option 3:
 role_desc: str | None =
    Field(
        min_length=5,
        max_length=200,
        examples=["Role description is provided here"],
        default=None,
    ),
]
```

All of the above implementations are giving the same error.

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "type": "string_too_short",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "role_desc"
      ],
      "msg": "String should have at least 5 characters",
      "input": "",
      "ctx": {
        "min_length": 5
      },
      "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/string_too_short"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any possible solution to have data field that validates only if some strings are provided, otherwise pass the `None`.

Comment: Your examples work fine with Pydantic v2.4 - what does your actual request look like? Are you sending `null` / `None` (or leaving the field out), or an empty string? Both `bar: constr(min_length=5, max_length=200) = None` and `bar: Annotated[Optional[str], Field(min_length=5, max_length=200, default=None)]` works as expected.

Comment: I am sending empty string as you can notice in validation error message too **"input": ""** .  If i leaving it out completely is giving me error as **"Invalid Json" input {}**.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289969/17865804)

Answer (score 2):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289969/17865804), when a **field** is declared as **optional**, users are **not required** to pass a value for that field in their HTTP request. Hence, users can leave that field out of the request, which, in that case, would default to `None`.

In your example, however, since you specify the `input` field's value in your client's HTTP request as `"input": ""`, this means that you pass an empty `str` (which is not the same as `None`) for the `input` field, and hence, the **restrictions** specified for that [`Field()`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/fields/#pydantic.fields.Field) **will be applied**. In turn, that leads to the error that you got, i.e., `"String should have at least 5 characters"`, since you specified `min_length=5` in that `Field()`. Thus, if you need to keep the value for a field set to `None`, all you have to do is to avoid sending a value for it in the client's HTTP request.