# Swagger not handling null types

Tags: swagger, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi, pydantic

**Problem**: When definining a query parameter type of 'optional enum', then Swagger UI is not showing a dropdown item anymore.

Swagger (typescript) code generators are not able to handle null types either. Most code generators I checked are switching to `any` type if a nullable type is used.
On the other hand pydantic 2 requires to set an optional type which wasn't the case in pydantic 1.

Recent fastapi version also switched from openapi 3.0.4 to openapi 3.1.0 whereas little amount of libraries are supporting it. Especially null types seems not to be supported by any of them.

`type: CategoryType | Query()`

[image: Swagger-UI with non optional query parameter.]

`type: CategoryType | None = Query(default=None)`

[image: Swagger-UI with optional query parameter not showing dropdown anymore.]

**Question:** Is there a solution to solve this problem? Hacky solutions are welcome too. Thanks for any advice.

What I've already tried:

- Tried to downgrade openapi version without downgrading fastapi => Not possible
- Tried to downgrade to pydantic 1 without downgrading fastapi => Not possible because of dependency conflicts.
- Tried to use different code generators and upgrading swagger-ui => No solution yet.
- Also started a discussion here: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/10595.

Version info: FastAPI Version: 0.103.0, Pydantic Version 2.4.2, Openapi Version: 3.1.0

Comment: There is no `none` type in OpenAPI or JSON Schema which is what OAS is based on.   They do have a `null` type. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I renamed the title.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289969/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77351372/17865804) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To effectively eliminate null types from your JSON schema, the `SkipJsonSchema` feature has been introduced. This enhancement, explained in [Fastapi pull request 6653](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/pull/6653), ensures that the SDK generator avoids the use of `any`.

```
from pydantic.json_schema import SkipJsonSchema
my_field: str | SkipJsonSchema[None]
```

It's important to note that tools like Swagger Codegen and OpenAPI Generator have yet to update for full compatibility with OpenAPI 3.1+.