# FASTapi doesn't handle Pydatnic validation error

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

in FASTapi aplication I have a `model.py`

```
class Testing(BaseModel):
    
    a: Optional[str]
    b: Optional[str]
    
    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def check_all_values(cls, values):
        if len(values) == 0:
            raise ValueError('Error...')
        
        return values
```

in `main.py` I have imported `Testing` class from `model.py`

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/', response_model=Testing)
async def postSomething(values: Testing):
    
    try:
        return values
    
    except ValueError as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=422, detail=f'{e}')
```

Now if you run this code and pass None to both arguments via API, the FASTapi will return 200, despite it should throw up an error. Why is this happening and what is the correct way or best practice to handle Pydatnic Validation errors via FASTapi. Would really appreciate your reply.

Comment: Since all values are optional, `values` will have keys for `a` and `b` with the value `None`. Since the dictionary has keys, it will have two as its length. You can probably do `if not any(values.values())` to check if at least one of the values are set (and validation happens before the function, so you won't be able to catch the exception there as noted in the answer below).

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72289969/17865804) answer your question? Please have a look at related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Request parameters are validated before the endpoint function run. So, you can't catch this exception inside endpoint.

But you can specify the exception handler and handle this error there:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": exc.errors(), "body": exc.body}),
    )


class Item(BaseModel):
    title: str
    size: int


@app.post("/items/")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return item
```

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#use-the-requestvalidationerror-body

And in your code it shouldn't cause the validation error if you pass `None` for both attributes, because your attributes are `Optional` and `None` is correct value. But if you pass empty dict it will couse `ValidationError`

Comment: One thing to make this a perfect answer is to make the code use the same models and routes as in the question, i.e. use `Testing` model and use that as the `response_model` in the route. The `Testing` model in the question incorrectly checks `values` instead of the keys inside `values`. So even if the OP copied your validation exception handler, the validation still won't work properly. You are right though about using an exception handler rather than catching the exception in the route.

Comment: @Yurii Motov

I am working on this for couple of days. I reinstalled everything, I changed ValueError to ValidationError, but now I get Internal Server Error, despite copying your code for exception.handler

Comment: Just  look at the error text in the terminal output